# How to open keyboard automatically in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a screen in my React Native application in which I have few text fields.

I was wondering if there is any way in which on screen load my keyword opens automatically  and focuses on my first text input field?

I was searching for something like `stateAlwaysVisible` in android.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The keyboard should open automatically when `<TextInput />` is focused. You can use the `autoFocus` prop to make it focus when the element mounts ([link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#autofocus))

Comment: Looks like i missed this while going through the documentation :( .. let me try it once...

Comment: `autoFocus` does not seem to fire when the page loads through stack navigation. It ends up focusing the `textInput` but does not open the keyboard.

Comment: i need to show the user this page has textInput, so when i navigate to this page the textInput should focus and also keyboard should open automatically .. how to do that? @Ziarno

Comment: does `<TextField autoFocus />` not work for you? it should focus the field on mount, and the keyboard should show

Comment: Manual focus by refs doesn't trigger keyboard. There is a Keyboard.dismiss(), but I don't see a show() on React Native docs either.

Comment: @Dan same problem here. Trying to focus a TextInput by ref and open the Keyboard. Did you find any solution?

Comment: This answer does not answers the question, it is a workaround for a specific case. If one doesn't wants/can use autofocus, then this answer won't work. The Keyboard is not shown on focus

Comment: can confirm that autoFocus works on android with stack navigation

Comment: anybody has made it work? autoFocus doesnt fix it for me.

Answer (score 23):

This trick worked for me

```
setTimeout(() => InputRef.current.focus(), 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works very well for me

Answer (score 17):

My way (there was a problem with focusing and showing a keyboard on component render)

```
import { InteractionManager, TextInput } from 'react-native';

...

inputRef = React.createRef();

componentDidMount() {
  this.focusInputWithKeyboard()
}

focusInputWithKeyboard() {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    this.inputRef.current.focus()
  });
}

render() {
  <TextInput ref={this.inputRef} />
}
```

Answer (score 13):

another solution :)

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

export function mycomponent(props) {
   const inputRef = useRef();
   
   return(
         <TextInput 
           ref={inputRef}
           onLayout={()=> inputRef.current.focus()}>
         </TextInput>
   )
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer that just work ! In case you're trying to focus an input inside a modal, use the Modal onShow event instead of the TextInput onLayout and it will work flowlessly.
<Modal visible={visible} onShow={() => inputRef.current?.focus()}/><TextInput ref={inputRef} /></Modal>

Comment: `onLayout` doesn't invoked when navigating back to that screen!

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me.

```
<TextInput
        autoFocus={false}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        onChangeText={(val) => {
            props.onChange(val);
        }}
        value={null}
        defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
        ref={(ref) => {

            if( ref !== undefined && ref && !ref.isFocused() ){

                ref.focus();
            }
        }}
        {...propsMerge}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working in my simulator. Have not confirmed on a real device.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.buildNameTextInput = React.createRef();
}
```

```html
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.mainButton}
  onPress={() => {
    this.buildNameTextInput = true
    this.props.setSaveBuildModal(true)
  }}
>
  <Text style={styles.mainButtonText}> Save Build </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TextInput
  autoFocus={!!this.buildNameTextInput}
  ref={this.buildNameTextInput}
  placeholder="Type a Name"
  autoCapitalize="words"
  style={{...styles.heroBtnText, marginVertical: 50}}
  onChangeText={buildName => this.props.setCurrentBuildName(buildName)}
  value={this.props.buildName}
/>
```

1. I needed the constructor to register the reference
2. The handler sets a local variable to true
3. autoFocus will trigger the field to be focused. The keyboard sometimes opens up on android simulator (this I cannot explain).
4. ref is for the reference to the DOM element

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a ref to the TextInput as
textInputRef
and use this.textInputRef.focus()

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks in code, using the setTimeout() Hook

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  setTimeout(() => inputRef.current.focus(), 100);
  return (
    <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
      <Text>circle</Text>
      <TextInput ref={inputRef} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: wrap the `setTimeOut` with `useEffect` or it will be it will be created in every render!

Comment: Just for clarify some things: 
1) `setTimeout` is not a hook, it's nothing but a JS function.
2) You need to wrap with `useEffect` hook, as said before.
3) It's a good practice to cancel it when component unmounts (returning a cleanup function in the end of `useEffect`), like following:
`useEffect(()=> {
const timeout = setTimeout(() => inputRef.current.focus(), 100);
return ()=> { clearTimeout(timeout) }
}, [])`

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me when using a `Modal`. However, a combination of them did work.

Using the Modal's `onShow` and a `setTimeout` did the job for me.

```
<Modal
  onShow={() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      inputRef?.current?.focus()
    }, 50)
  }}
>
  {/* ... */}
  <TextInput
    ref={inputRef}
  />
</Modal>
```

Answer (score -1):

The selected solution did not work for me due to stack navigation (see comment of "SoundStage" on selected solution)

I added a new variable `openTheKeyboard` to the state initially set to `false`.

My hacky solution:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ openTheKeyboard: true });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.openTheKeyboard) {
    this.textInput.focus();
    this.setState({ openTheKeyboard: false });
  }
}
```

Comment: What could be the reasons if when calling `.focus()` the keyboard is not showing up ?

Comment: this.textInput.focus(); should instead be this.textInput.current.focus();