# React Native- Persist keyboard when dialog show

Tags: react-native, keyboard, modal-dialog, hide, dismiss

My react native version is 0.55.4 , when modal showing keyboard dismiss , how can show modal without dismissing keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need a little hack!

For example you can auto focus on a input in your modal ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456069/how-to-open-keyboard-automatically-in-react-native))

Or use a custom modal that not related with native keyboard (You can write this yourself or use some package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal))

Comment: i use react-native-modal but same issue

Comment: why you want show keyboard without TextInput? you try with auto focus? @ArmanKabir