# Is there any way to handel onClose keyboard device button in React native?

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

I want to never allow close the keyboard in my screen so i try to handel this button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard should open automatically when a `<TextField />` is focused. You can use the `autoFocus` prop to make it focus when the element mounts [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#autofocus)

Also, you can check this answer

[How to open keyboard automatically in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456069/how-to-open-keyboard-automatically-in-react-native)

By the way, you want to control the hardware back button for this, to visit this link

[React Native - Device back button handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031085/react-native-device-back-button-handling)

here is the sample code for hardware back button.

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank for you answer but all of these are not my solution ,i want to dont allow user to close the keyboard

Comment: can you share your code, maybe I can fix it after looking your code